# Two Dropbox folders in one computer

Tags: dropbox

I have a Dropbox account and want to store folders on two different drives, and have them both backed up etc by Dropbox. How can I do that?

Comment: What operating system? Do you have a pro account?

Comment: Windows 7, I have a standard account.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to "cheat" the system by using Junction Points in NTFS.

1. Install Dropbox, following the full setup including your account
2. Exit Dropbox (right-click the icon in the system tray and click **Exit**)
3. Open an Administrative Command Prompt (**Start**->type `cmd`->right-click the top entry and click `Run as Administrator` and select <kbd>Yes</kbd>)
4. Type the following command: `mklink /J %USERPROFILE%\Dropbox\Foldername X:\Foldername` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Repeat the above command for any other folders, replacing the *Foldername* with the name you want to use, and *X:\Foldername* with the current folder
6. Relaunch Dropbox

Junction points will basically make another pointer to the directory, usually transparent to most programs

Comment: what's the difference here if I use the /H or /D parameters in mklink? Since I would like to do this for my localserver, I don't want the files copied from one folder to another every time, as there will be quite a number of reads/writes to be done. Basically the whole point of this is to move my XAMPP installation to an SSD rather than a normal drive where it used to reside alongside all the other folders I have in Dropbox.

Comment: @drtanz With `/J`, it just creates a junction or pointer to that folder. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) has a full write-up on it if you follow the links